# Filtering datatype date with Datepicker directive in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datepicker, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ngmodel

I'm using datepicker directive by from [UI Bootstrap](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/datepicker). I want to return all data from SQL Server DB when I'm choosing a date from the datepicker button. How I have to do to pass to get the data from a chosen date?

Firstly my View:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <p class="input-group">
            <input type="text" 
                    class="form-control" 
                    datepicker-popup="{{format}}" 
                    ng-model="search.dt" 
                    is-open="opened" 
                    min-date="" 
                    max-date="''" 
                    datepicker-options="dateOptions" 
                    date-disabled="disabled(date, mode)" 
                    ng-required="true" 
                    close-text="Close" 
                    />
            <span class="input-group-btn">
               <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open($event)"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
            </span>
        </p>
     </div>
</div>
...
//Here comes the ngRepeat directive with the table list
<tr ng-repeat="report in repDay | filter: search">
   <td>{{ report.datum | date:'dd.MM.yyyy' }}</td>
...
</tr>
...
```

Finally the Controller:

```
/* GET all data from the database table */
$scope.repDay = resService.query();

//date format
$scope.format = 'dd.MM.yyyy';

// Button Open
$scope.open = function ($event) {
  $event.preventDefault();
  $event.stopPropagation();

  $scope.opened = true;
};

$scope.dateOptions = {
  formatYear: 'yy',
  startingDay: 1
};
```

I guess the problem is coming from the date format isn't it? Because when I'm trying to choose a date from the picker then the data result is empty and the table view too.

Comment: Have you tried changing your filter value to `search.dt` instead of just `search`?

Comment: @Matt Yes I did.. But it doesn't work. I have to pass the input from ngModel to the table column `report.datum`

Comment: @Matt The problem is the format. I'm trying my example in a simple input field only with `ngModel = search.datum` and `type = text`. When I'm typing `03.01.2013` then they're filtering the table. When I change the input type to `date` then it is filtering the table only by input such like this: `03.01.2013T00..` with the time because the data in the database contains the type Datetime.